# jquery: Overlapping slideup div's. Clicking to fast messes it up

Tags: jquery, html, slideup, overlapping

i'm having a problem with sliding divs using jquery. If I click the links to fast (for example the first link and right away the second link) the divs will overlap (what they should not do!). Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("div.slide").hide();

$('a.link').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var slideSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('link', 'slide');

  $('div.slide').not(slideSelector).slideUp(1000, 'easeOutQuart', function() {
    $(slideSelector).slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuart');
  });


  });      

});

</script>
```

Take a look at the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eEkk6/) and see what I mean. I would be very happy to hear from you guys!!

Comment: try using jQuery's `.stop()` function in conjunction.  Like: `$(slideSelector).stop().slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuart');
`

Comment: thank you so much, but it won't fix it...

Comment: I think my answer is the one you need, i tried it a couple times and it doesn't mess up anymore :) http://jsfiddle.net/eEkk6/5/ <-- updated version of yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm just add a boolean to check if it is clicked? I quickly tested it with my trackpad and it should work

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{    
    $("div.slide").hide();
    var clicked = false;
    $('a.link').on('click', function(e) 
   {

       if(!clicked)
       {
        e.preventDefault();
        clicked = true;
        var slideSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('link', 'slide');

      $('div.slide').not(slideSelector).slideUp(1000, function() 
      {
          $(slideSelector).slideDown(1000, function(){
          clicked = false;
          });
      });
        }

  });      

});​
```

Comment: thank you so much! but when i use your code in my original webdesign it messes everything up... no animations and all divs overlap... :(

Comment: hmmm you might have a typo in ur code, check you console window :)